# H1 Border not to strech

Tags: html, background, header, styles

I have a `h1` element with a background color:

```
 <h1 style="color:#b6ff00;background-color:aqua; text-align:center;">Choose time for the appointment</h1>
```

now this places the background color to be stretched across the entire window.

Can I contain it just within the size of the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `span` in the h1, apply the border to that.

```
<h1 style="text-align:center;">
 <span style="color:#b6ff00;background-color:aqua;">
   Choose time for the appointment
 </span>
</h1>
```

The reason why this happens is that `h1` is a [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) (stretching across the entire available width of its container) and `span` is an inline element (not stretching across the entire width, but occupying only as much space as is needed to display it.)

Comment: Yes, this does the trick, sorry for wasting your time with stupid questions like this, I still have to learn the Elements of HTML. I'll mark it as correct and answered when the 10mins restriction passes. Thank You for Your time :)
And 1 more question, is it now possible to place items around h1 like left of h1 or right of h1?

Comment: @MicroDev it is - usually the best way to do that is to use `float`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Floats

Comment: This is what I was looking for, just gotta study it a bit, Thanks a lot for Your help! :)